# Text decoding issue from google translate API in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, urlencode, google-translate

So here is the URL:

```
https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=ar-SA&tl=en-US&dt=t&q=سلام
```

The response is all fine when is hit from **Browser** or **Postman**. But when i do it through code, there are weird strings when getting a response.

I tried **Alamofire**:

```
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get, parameters: nil,encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted, headers: ["Accept":"application/json;charset=UTF-8" ]).responseJSON { response in

            print(response)
}
```

The response string is something like this:

```
"\\U0637\\U00b3\\U0638\\U201e\\U0637\\U00a7\\U0638\\U2026"
```

and also this weird Arabic string.

```
"ط ط ط \\\"\\\" ط ... ... ...\"
```

I **also** tried hitting URL like this:

```
String.init(data: Data.init(contentsOf: URL.init(string: "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=ar-SA&tl=en-US&dt=t&q=%E2%80%8F%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85")!), encoding: .utf8)
```

But the result is the same, some weird Arabic strings, which is different when is hit from *browser* or *postman*.

```
"ط ط ط \\\"\\\" ط ... ... ...\"
```

I am encoding URL before hitting URL. Also tried different encodings on url and string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the issue with the parameters of API. I added these 2 parameters and it worked all fine.

```
ie=UTF-8
oe=UTF-8
```